# Cannot upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 18.04

I really hope nobody gets nazi-esque on me for asking this (or edits my post for making such a joke... even worse), but I can't upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04

I've tried using `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
I've tried using `sudo apt do-release-upgrade`
I've also tried using `sudo update-manager`

But it's not working. When I input `lsb_release -a` it still says I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (not a typo, I originally used Ubuntu and switched over to Kubuntu when I got sick of Unity/Gnome pretentiousness).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this same problem but I found running the following worked for me

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

See if that works for you

Comment: Fantastic. This worked for me. Thank you much!