# could not start kdeinit5 after Kubuntu upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I wanted to update my kubuntu form 17.10 to 18.04 and i found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029049/cannot-upgrade-to-kubuntu-18-04/1029209).

I used:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and it did something, but when I restarted only a black screen appears with the KDE PLASMA mouse cursor and a popup says:

> could not start kdeinit5 check your installation

with an OK Button

What I tried so far: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login.

`inxi -F` says that is have Kubuntu 18.04. So that's what I wanted

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

can't install libqt5xcbqpa5.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install plasma-desktop
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

it works again. 
i have this mesa ppa https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
and before the update all 3rd party ppa get deactivated.
i forgot about that. i just added the repository again and did "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"

thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would try a few things. Firstly, try doing CTRL+ALT+F2 again and after you put in your login and password input

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Also try

```
sudo apt install --fix-missing
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(P.S. for god's sake folks please don't downvote me for just trying to help.)

Comment: Also, when I first tried to upgrade a lot of software wasn't properly upgraded, so you might have to input a
 `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` 
as well to resume installing those updates.

Comment: nope, that didnt help